# Separating a harmonically driven ODE into oscillating and non-oscillating components

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, steady-state, oscillatory-integral

Consider the first-order ODE
$$
x'(t) = f(t) \cos(\omega t) - \gamma x(t)
$$
whose exact solution is
$$
x(t) = x(0) e^{-\gamma t} + \int_0^t e^{-\gamma (t-t')} \cos(\omega t') f(t')~dt'
$$
For simple forms of $f(t)$, the time-history integral may be performed and one often finds that there is a non-oscillatory term and two oscillating terms, one in-phase with the drive and one out -of-phase.
For example if $f(t) = f_0$ is constant, then
$$
x(t) = \left[x(0) - \frac{\gamma}{\gamma^2 + \omega^2}\right] e^{-\gamma t} + \frac{\gamma f_0 \cos(\omega t)}{\gamma^2 + \omega^2} + \frac{\omega f_0\sin(\omega t)}{\gamma^2 + \omega^2}\tag{$\star$}
$$
The first term does not oscillate, the second term oscillates in phase with the drive, and the third oscillates out of phase.
For more complicated $f(t)$, it seems reasonable to expect similar qualitative behavior and to try to extract each type of term with the ansatz
$$
x(t)=x_0(t) + \Re[x_1(t)\exp(-i\omega t)]
$$
where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are supposed to be non-oscillatory.
Putting this in to the original ODE, I obtain
$$
x_0'(t) + \gamma x_0(t) + \Re\left[\left(x_1' + \gamma x_1 - i\omega x_1 - f\right) \exp(-i\omega t)\right]  = 0
$$
My instinct is to attempt to treat each "Fourier component" independently
$$\begin{align}
& x'_0(t) + \gamma x_0(t) = 0 \\
& x'_1(t) + \gamma x_1(t) - i\omega x_1(t) = f(t)
\end{align}$$
However, this appears not to work as hoped, because the solution for $x_1$ will clearly have an oscillation at the drive frequency $\omega$, due to the term $-i\omega x_1$.
For the constant drive case, I have explicitly
$$\begin{align}
& x_0(t) = x_0(0) e^{-\gamma t} \\
& x_1(t) = \left[x_1(0) - \frac{(\gamma + i\omega)f_0}{\gamma^2+\omega^2}  \right] e^{-\gamma t} e^{i\omega t} + \frac{(\gamma + i\omega)f_0}{\gamma^2 + \omega^2}
\end{align}$$
In this case, I can actually eliminate the problematic oscillatory term in $x_1$ by choosing to split the initial conditions according to
$$
x_0(0) = x(0) - \frac{\gamma f_0}{\gamma^2 + \omega^2}, \quad
x_1(0) = \frac{\gamma + i\omega}{\gamma^2 + \omega^2} f_0
$$
In which case I obtain the full solution ($\star$) for $x(t)$, now with the non-oscillatory and oscillatory parts cleanly separated.

So the question I'm interested in is: does this procedure generalize for any (reasonable) $f(t)$? That is, suppose I cannot analytically solve the $x_1$ equation, is there a way to pick out the oscillating and non-oscillating parts? An approximate or asymptotic method would be welcome as well.

Comment: If $f$ is periodic, you can use the first terms of its Fourier series to get an approximation of this form, applying your reasoning for each term.